# Move Nth element from a div picked in an each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Consider the following code:

```
jQuery(function($)
{
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
      $(".td-block-row").each(function()
      {
        var item = $(this);
        $(".td-block-span4:nth-child(3)").prependTo(item.next());
      });
  });
});
```

I am trying to iterate through each `.td-block-row` div, and pick out the third `.td-block-span4` element from it, and then move it to the next `.td-block-row`

The code I currently have (above) will move *every* Nth `.td-block-span4` rather than just the one within the current div in the each loop. Essentially I am trying to do something like:

```
$(item ".td-block-span4:nth-child(3)").prependTo(item.next());
```

This may just be a case of finding out the correct syntax to make use of the item var, or perhaps I am taking a completely the wrong approach.

Any advise here would be appreciated as I have little experience with JS

Comment: `$(".td-block-span4:nth-child(3)", this).prependTo(item.next());`

Comment: Can you create a demo like https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8hxqaove/1/

Comment: Arun the first comment worked perfectly. I suppose this is just a case of my newbishness to JS syntax. Cheers!

Comment: You can find inside the context like this: `item.find(".td-block-span4:nth-child(3)").prependTo(item.next());`

Comment: Why don't you add the markup ?

Comment: Because the issue is JS logic, it doesn't matter how the HTML is set out provided that there are 3 or more elements called .td-block-span4 in each -td-block-row. I didn't want to crowd the question with irrelevent content

Comment: @Aphire Did you get the solution ?

Comment: I did indeed, just waiting one more minute before I can accept the answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you need to query `td-block-span4:nth-child(3)` relative to the current element(in the each handler). So

```
$(".td-block-span4:nth-child(3)", this).prependTo(item.next());
//or
$item.find(".td-block-span4:nth-child(3)").prependTo(item.next());
```